# Parse yaml list elements one at a time in python

Tags: python, yaml

Is there a yaml library in python that can read an input file an entry at a time, as needed, rather than parsing the whole file? I have a long file with list as the root node. If I'm trying to find the first element satisfying a certain property, I may not need to read and parse the whole file, and get the result faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PyYAML's low-level `parse()` API:

```
import yaml

for event in yaml.parse(input):
    # process event
```

The events are documented [here](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#events).

If you want to construct each item of a root-level sequence into a native Python value, you need to use the `Composer` and `Constructor` classes. `Composer` reads events and transforms them into *nodes*, `Constructor` builds Python values from *nodes*. This corresponds to the loading process defined in the YAML spec:

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaml.org](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/overview2.png))</sub>

Now PyYAML's `Composer` expects functions `get_event`, `check_event` and `peek_event` to exist on `self`, but doesn't implement them. They are implemented by `Parser`. Therefore, to have a working YAML loading chain, PyYAML later does:

```
class Loader(Reader, Scanner, Parser, Composer, Constructor, Resolver):
  def __init__(self, stream):
    Reader.__init__(self, stream)
    Scanner.__init__(self)
    Parser.__init__(self)
    Composer.__init__(self)
    Constructor.__init__(self)
    Resolver.__init__(self)
```

For you, this means that you need a `Loader` object and use the `Parser` API for top-level events, along with the `Composer` and `Constructor` API to load each item in the top-level sequence.

Here's some code that gets you started:

```
import yaml

input = """
- "A": 1
- "B": 2
- foo
- 1
"""

loader = yaml.SafeLoader(input)

# check proper stream start (should never fail)
assert loader.check_event(yaml.StreamStartEvent)
loader.get_event()
assert loader.check_event(yaml.DocumentStartEvent)
loader.get_event()

# assume the root element is a sequence
assert loader.check_event(yaml.SequenceStartEvent)
loader.get_event()

# now while the next event does not end the sequence, process each item
while not loader.check_event(yaml.SequenceEndEvent):
    # compose current item to a node as if it was the root node
    node = loader.compose_node(None, None)
    # construct a native Python value with the node.
    # we set deep=True for complete processing of all the node's children
    value = loader.construct_object(node, True)
    print(value)

# assume document ends and no further documents are in stream
loader.get_event()
assert loader.check_event(yaml.DocumentEndEvent)
loader.get_event()
assert loader.check_event(yaml.StreamEndEvent)
```

Be aware that you might run into problems if you have anchors & aliases in the YAML document.

Comment: This seems exactly like what I'm looking for, but after looking at the documentation I still don't understand how this part of the API works. For example, if my yaml input is `'- "A": 1\n- "B": 2'`, how do I parse the elements of the outer list one by one? Do I somehow bind functions to event types?

Comment: Added example code to demonstrate construction of values from event sub-lists